# postgresql How show most frequent value per day date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a problem with a query that is supposed to return the value which occur most per date

```
+------------+------------------+
|    Date    |      value       |
+------------+------------------+
| 2020-01-01 | Programmer       |
| 2020-01-02 | Technician       |
| 2020-01-03 | Business Analyst |
+------------+------------------+
```

So far I have done

```
select count(headline) as asd, publication_date, employer -> 'name' as dsa from jobhunter
group by publication_date,dsa
ORDER BY publication_date  DESC
```

But it shows 2020-12-31 19:06:00 instead of just YYYY-MM-DD
Any idea on how to fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oL8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

Test data:

```
create table tbl (
    id serial primary key,
    row_datetime TIMESTAMP,
    row_val VARCHAR(60)
);

insert into tbl (row_datetime, row_val) values ('2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'a');
insert into tbl (row_datetime, row_val) values ('2021-01-01 01:00:00', 'a');
insert into tbl (row_datetime, row_val) values ('2021-01-01 02:00:00', 'b');
insert into tbl (row_datetime, row_val) values ('2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'a');
insert into tbl (row_datetime, row_val) values ('2021-01-02 01:00:00', 'b');
insert into tbl (row_datetime, row_val) values ('2021-01-02 02:00:00', 'b');
```

Example query:

```
SELECT dt, val, cnt
FROM (
   SELECT dt, val, cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS row_num
   FROM (
      SELECT dt, val, COUNT(val) AS cnt
      FROM (
         SELECT DATE(row_datetime) AS dt, row_val AS val FROM tbl
      ) AS T1 GROUP BY dt, val
   ) AS T2
) AS T3
WHERE row_num=1
ORDER BY dt ASC
```

You can additionally customize your query to optimize the performance, get more fields, etc.